# xml xsl template with html / js inside failing

Tags: xml, xslt

im doing a quick update for a site but xslt is not my thing and it seems to be failing with the code i code looking at the generated source - have included both below:

current code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets" xmlns:tagsLib="urn:tagsLib"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library Exslt.ExsltCommon Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes Exslt.ExsltMath Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions Exslt.ExsltStrings Exslt.ExsltSets tagsLib ">


<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:if test="string-length($currentPage/mp4videoLinkId) > 0">
  <xsl:variable name="videoID" select="$currentPage/mp4videoLinkId" />
  <xsl:variable name="srtID" select="$currentPage/mp4videoSRTId" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="flowplayer-3.2.6.min.js"></script>
  <script src="flowplayer.ipad-3.2.2.min.js"></script>

  <!-- player container-->
  <a href="{$videoID}" style="display:block;width:473px;height:310px;" id="ipad"></a>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $f("ipad", "flowplayer-3.2.7.swf",{
    clip: {
      autoPlay: false,
      url: '{$videoID}',

      // this is the Timed Text file with captions info
      captionUrl: '{$srtID}'
    },
    plugins:  {

      captions: {
        url: 'flowplayer.captions-3.2.3.swf',

        // pointer to a content plugin (see below)
        captionTarget: 'content'
      },

      // configure a content plugin to look good for our purpose
      content: {
        url:'flowplayer.content-3.2.0.swf',
        bottom: 25,
        width: '80%',
        height:40,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        backgroundGradient: 'none',
        borderRadius: 4,
        border: 0,
        textDecoration: 'outline',
        style: {
          body: {
            fontSize: 14,
            fontFamily: 'Arial',
            textAlign: 'center',
            color: '#ffffff'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }).ipad();
  </script>  
</xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

generated source:
(as you can see it breaking the code and not closing  and then showing the {$tags}) what am i missing?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" /><script src="flowplayer-3.2.6.min.js" /><script src="flowplayer.ipad-3.2.2.min.js" /><a href="mp4/assist-mi-car-parking.mp4" style="display:block;width:473px;height:310px;" id="ipad" /><script type="text/javascript">
  $f("ipad", "flowplayer-3.2.7.swf",{
    clip: {
      autoPlay: false,
      url: '{$videoID}',

      // this is the Timed Text file with captions info
      captionUrl: '{$srtID}'
    },
    plugins:  {

      captions: {
        url: 'flowplayer.captions-3.2.3.swf',

        // pointer to a content plugin (see below)
        captionTarget: 'content'
      },

      // configure a content plugin to look good for our purpose
      content: {
        url:'flowplayer.content-3.2.0.swf',
        bottom: 25,
        width: '80%',
        height:40,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        backgroundGradient: 'none',
        borderRadius: 4,
        border: 0,
        textDecoration: 'outline',
        style: { 
          body: { 
            fontSize: 14, 
            fontFamily: 'Arial',
            textAlign: 'center',
            color: '#ffffff'
          } 
        } 
      }
    }
  }).ipad();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AVT **[(Attribute Value Template) convention in XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)** is defined only for attribute values -- as the name of this feature clearly says.

Expressions inside curly braces that are part of a text node **are not evaluated**. One needs to use the `<xsl:value-of>` instruction.

**Solution**:

**Replace**:

```
url: '{$videoID}',
```

**with**:

```
url: '<xsl:value-of select="$videoID"/>',
```

**Similarly replace**:

```
  captionUrl: '{$srtID}'
```

**with:**

```
  captionUrl: '<xsl:value-of select="$srtID"/>'
```

Comment: great, that is now showing the data! however it is still only including the jquery and nothing after that looking in firebug, and in source its not closing the </script> and i think that preventing rest from showing.....

Comment: @JamesBrandon: Your XSLT transformation may have additional errors -- you need to show a complete (but as small as possible in order to reproduce the problem) XML document, a complete (as small as possible but reproducing the problem) XSLT transformation, the complete result you get, the complete result you *want* to get and any rules that the transformation must implement. As for this question, it has been answered completely. Please, ask a new question for the rest of the problems and provide all necessary information for reproducing this new problem.